How to switch Bevy engine from f32 to f64 type?
I want to switch the type for translation across all components of my project. I know there are special f64-based types, but how to enable them for the entire engine? For example for the Transform component? Is there something like DTransform?

It's not supported yet. Bevy team plans to change it for more flexibility, see the status by this discussion issues/1680.
Currently, the best way to fix rendering and calculations when you work with large distances is to use big_space plugin.
From the big_space docs:


Disable Bevy’s transform plugin: DefaultPlugins.build().disable::<TransformPlugin>()
Add the BigSpacePlugin to your App
Spawn a BigSpace with spawn_big_space, and spawn entities in it.
Add the FloatingOrigin to your active camera in the BigSpace.


